# How can I join the last table onto this triple join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which I've modelled on a branch of a super market.
Basically what I want to do is a join to output the Customer Name, their basket ID, The cashier (type of employees) Id and the subsequent Name of the employee who serves then.
I've managed to do a triple table join and show the basketID,EmployeeId and the employee name, but also want to get the customer's name at the start but have no idea how to.

I've pasted the bits of SQL in question.

```
create table Employee
(
name char(30),
employeeID integer(20) primary key,
);



create table Cashier
(
tillID integer(4) primary key,
employeeID integer(20),
foreign key (employeeID) references adbc921_Employee (employeeID)
);

create table Customer
(
customerID integer(20) primary key,
first_name char(20),
last_name char(20),
);

create table CustomerInStorePurchase
(
customerID integer(20),
number_of_items integer(3),
tillID integer(4),
basketID integer(10),
foreign key (tillID) references adbc921_Cashier (tillID),
foreign key(customerID) references adbc921_Customer (customerID),
foreign key (basketID) references adbc921_Basket (basketID)
);

create table Basket
(
basketID integer(10),
customerID integer(20),
foreign key (customerID) references adbc921_CustomerInStorePurchase (customerID),
foreign key (productID) references adbc921_Product (productID)
);
```

Comment: It looks like you left out the end of the `adbc921_Cashier` table definition.

Comment: What's the problem? Just add another join with `adbc921_Customer`.

Comment: FYI you don't need parentheses around the joins.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another join with the customer table.

```
Select p.basketID, c.employeeId, e.name, cus.customerID, cus.first_name, cus.last_name
FROM adbc921_CustomerInStorePurchase AS p
Inner Join adbc921_Cashier AS c on p.tillID = c.tillID
Inner Join adbc921_Employee AS e on c.employeeID = e.employeeID
inner join adbc921_Customer AS cus on cus.customerID = p.customerID
```

I strongly recommend employing table aliases in queries, especially when you have such long table names. It removes lots of repeated clutter that makes queries hard to read.

Comment: You have a typo: `91` should be `921`

Comment: Using aliases avoids problems like that.

Comment: Why do you think you need to nest all the joins in parentheses like that?

Comment: On W3Schools they use parentheses on their joins.

Comment: Many of us consider w3schools the worst of the tutorial sites. Unfortunately, they're also very popular and end up at the top of google searches.

Comment: Ah I see. It's just they have good examples and explain things quite simply. What sites would you recommend for good tutorial on most things?

Comment: I can't really recommend specific sites, since I've rarely used any of them. I just know that w3schools has lots of obsolete info and a bad reputation.

Answer (score 0):

> Select adbc921_CustomerInStorePurchase.basketID,adbc921_Cashier.employeeId,adbc921_Employee.name, concat(adbc921_Customer.first_name,' ',adbc921_Customer.last_name)
> FROM ((adbc921_CustomerInStorePurchase
> Inner Join adbc921_Cashier on adbc921_CustomerInStorePurchase.tillID = adbc921_Cashier.tillID)
> Inner Join adbc921_Employee on adbc921_Cashier.employeeID = adbc921_Employee.employeeID)
> Inner Join adbc921_Customer on adbc921_Customer.customerID=adbc921_CustomerInStorePurchase.customerID

If im not wrong you got a reference between customer table and customerinStore, so why you dont use it?

Comment: Use code formatting, not quotation formatting.